# Applying for a B2 visa

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I hope someone can assist me. Last year I applied for a B1 visa. A US company I worked for invited me for training. I went for the interview and I was refused. I was asked why I was going, who was paying, would I be visiting other places besides those mentioned, and I said yes. I am 31, single, I got a job as a software tester and I have my own property and look after my parents.

So the second time around I applied and the officer asked me what changed overnight and I did not lie to him. I told him, well sir I am invited by the company for training and we went back and forth in a polite way. Eventually he said it was approved and stated his only going to give me a 2-week visa. When I got the visa it was 3 months, which is the minimum B1, with an annotation. So when I got to the USA, the officer stamped it and added an extra 3 months.

I was there for the required period and came back home, did not overstay.

Now I am working for a new company.

- I have property.
- I want to visit a friend and attend festival in the USA.
- I got an invitation letter.
- I have a return ticket.
- I have a letter from work.
- I have letter from college, as I am still studying.
- I have a letter from my parents.
- I am single.

Would this be an issue if I applied for a B2 visa? I only need 1 week in USA then I must return.

Comment: Why would it be an issue? You correctly used the visa which increases your credibility.

Comment: @greatone thanks, maybe I am being paranoid...Wish me luck thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

Your profile is very "low-risk", and combined with the fact that you already used a US visa properly, you should have no problems getting a new one.

Do bring documentation proving your circumstances just in case.

**That said**, you usually get a combined B1/B2 visa. Check if this is what you have, because then you don't need a new one unless it's expired.

Comment: The visa I got the last time was B1 only and for 3 months. Wish me luck to get the 10 year visa next time.

Comment: @F-Society In the application form, select B1/B2 - that's the most common visa type. To be honest, if you can prove your circumstances and trip purpose, you should be able to get it

Comment: Last question, if I go for the next interview and the officer ask me how long im going to be there , and I mentioned say 1 week, can i mentioned more info , as to why and mention my strong ties or is it recommended that I just answer them saying 1 week and then move onto the next question.

Comment: @F-Society Only answer their questions

Comment: Thanks for the response. really appreciate.One last question sorry. So my friend lives in Tampa and he is providing me with an invite letter , going to spend a few days with him and then jetting off to Miami for the Ultra music festival.(I am going alone to that festival and then flying back) would this raise any concern if I mentioned this to the VO? if they ask where exactly im going for the 1 week.

Comment: @F-Society You tell the truth, i.e. what you wrote here. Nothing more, nothing less